# Call submodule functions within parent module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

How do you call a submodule's functions from within a parent module? The directory is setup like the following:

```
root/
     main.py
     moduleA/
             __init__.py
             submodule.py
             moduleB/
                    __init__.py
                    sub_submodule.py
```

The situation I am in is I need `submodule.py` to be able to use functions within `sub_submodule.py`. Under the first `__init__.py` within the `moduleA` directory I have the following:

`from .moduleB.sub_submodule import *`

This allows me to call sub_submodule from within the `__init__.py` file, but when I move to the next line:

`from .submodule import *`

Python navigates into the `submodule.py` script and I can't import or call `sub_submodule.py` functions. What key concept am I missing here? I've looked at other answers and documentation but am still lost.

Also, eventually I want `main.py` to be able to use functions in both `submodule.py` and `sub_submodule.py`. How will I go about that?

Comment: What do you mean by: "Python navigates into the submodule.py script and I can't import or call sub_submodule.py functions"?  You mean you can't call them from within `submodule.py`?

Comment: Correct. I used a print ("Hello") statement and Python is "in" `submodule.py.` When I try `moduleB.sub_submodule.myFunc()` I get `NameError: name 'moduleB' is not defined`. However if I try to do an import of module B within `submodule.py ` with the following: `import moduleB.sub_submodule` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleB'`